# Can Domain and Subdomain have same URL pattern on same server(.htaccess)?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I am creating mobile site for an existing site using "m" subdomain. 
I am stuck with htaccess rules. I am very new to htaccess and very bad with regex.

Site Name - xyz.com

Subdomain - m.xyz.com

I want that whenever my webpage is redirected( OR directly opened in) to mobile, subdomain should 
have exact same URL as main domain but should go to a mobile version file i.e.

Player

```
domain - xyz.com/5  -- real url - xyz.com/account.php?ln=5 (this account.php is in root folder)
Subdomain - m.xyz.com/5 -- real url - m.xyz.com/account.php?ln=5 (this account.php is in subfolder m)
```

Team

```
domain - xyz.com/TeamName/10  -- real url - xyz.com/team.php?ln=10 (this team.php is in root folder)
Subdomain - m.xyz.com/TeamName/10 -- real url - m.xyz.com/team.php?ln=10 (this team.php is in subfolder m)
```

Game

```
domain - xyz.com/GameName/18  -- real url - xyz.com/game.php?p=18&t=game (this game.php is in root folder)
Subdomain - m.xyz.com/GameName/18 -- real url - m.xyz.com/game.php?p=18&t=game (this game.php is in subfolder m)
```

xyz.com works perfectly for all combinations but when I hit subdomain it does not point to correct file.

when i try to hit m.xyz.com/TeamName/10 it redirects to http://m.xyz.com/m/game.php/?p=45&t=TeamName but should have gone to 
m.xyz.com/team.php?ln=5 (to the file in subfolder m). Direct URL works.

Directory Structure :

```
xyz(htdocs)
 |
 --- account.php
 |
 --- team.php
 |
 --- game.php
 |
 --- m (Subdirectory - Subdomain)
     |
     --- account.php
     |
     --- team.php
     |
     --- game.php
```

.htaccess file -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  #Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

  #Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php

  #player 1 Parameter = Account Id
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ account.php?ln=$1 [NC]

  #team 2 parameter = team name + team ID
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ team.php?ln=$2 [NC]

  #game page = game ID + game Name + type
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\/([a-z0-9_-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ game.php?p=$3&t=$2 [NC]


# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

Please have a look and let me know if you have any answer, searched on google for almost three days already no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh Nailed it.. it was a very simple catch .. dint realize i was missing the .htaccess in my subdomain folder (root/m). Copied the same htaccess in subdomain and it worked like charm. in simple words for other people who may try to find the answer for it...

Domain and subdomain both require a .htaccess file, if you are trying to create an exact domain copy site for mobile site you must be having files with same name in your subdomain directory you need to just place a copy of htaccess file in your subdomain which you are using for domain.

Dint realize it was so easy... stupid me... (This is how you learn :D )